# where to declare object to use it (fltk)

Tags: c++, heap-memory, fltk, stack-memory

I am having a problem accessing an object or its methods in fltk.
I have a Class named MyWindow which is a child class of Fl_Window.
so basically i would like to use an object which is either declared int the main or Mywindow in private section. My problem is that I can't use it that way. It only lets me to use the object if it is declared global. Can i somehow put it on the heap like this: Classname *pointer = new Classname();  ? IF i can where do I do that? 
How would the callback function work if i need that object or its functions in the callback?
Should i use a pointer to it in the callback arguements? 
lets say i want to click on the button and I need it to do something with the object and change a value.
lots of questions I know, I am really lost. 
Can someone just point me to the right direction? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple case for passing data to the GUI

```
class MyData
{
    // The data model
};

class MyWindow: public FL_Window
{
    MyData* m_data;
public:
    void Data(MyData* data) { m_data = data; }
    ...
};

int main()
{
    MyWindow gui;
    MyData data;

    // Tell the gui about the data
    gui.Data(data);
    ...
    // Setup the dialog
    gui.begin();
    ...
    gui.end();
    gui.show();
    return FL::run();
}
```

For the callbacks, do it in two stages

```
class NeedingACallback
{
public:
    void Setup()
    {
        ...
        FL_xxx* w = new FL_xxx(xpos, ypos, wid, hgt, name);
        ...
        //                    v Pass the instance to the static
        w->callback(_EventCB, this);
    }

    // The callback
    static void _EventCB(FL_Widget* w, void* client)
    {
        // Convert the void* back to the instance
        NeedingACallback* self = reinterpret_cast<NeedingACallback*>(client);
        self->EventCB();
    }

    // Make life simple so you don't have to put self-> in front of
    // all the instance data accessed
    void EventCB()
    {
        // Callback for this instance of the class
    }
};
```

**EDIT** It sounds like you're having multiple instances of data.  An alternative technique is to have data as a reference.  This must be done in the constructor.  This way, m_data and the data in main both refer to the same area of memory.

```
class MyWindow: public FL_Window
{
    MyData& m_data;
public:
    MyWindow(int wid, int hgt, MyData& data, const char* title=0)
   : FL_Window(wid,hgt,title)
   , m_data(data)
    {
    ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyData data;
    MyWindow gui(100, 100, data, "Call me Mr");

    ...
    // Setup the dialog
    gui.begin();
    ...
    gui.end();
    gui.show();
    return FL::run();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! it works!!!! the only problem is that it is a little bit ugly looking code:D . but i guess it is because FLTK is more C than C++. Thank you for all your help and code and time. It really helps me a lot!!

Comment: the only problem is that if I change something with the functions, it does not save the changes. So i can do the functions but nothing gets saved. for example i setup the players and they get a mark X or O which is pushed back in a vector, but when i call the getMark function it returns a random character, so I think it makes a copy of the object and does the function it is asked for and then deletes the object. Why is it so simple with globals and so hard when done properly?

Comment: Are you passing the data by value, by reference or by pointer?

Comment: I think i tried all of them but not sure if i was doing it right. I tried with your method first, to setup a pointer pointing to the object in main. 
class MyWindow: public FL_Window
{
    MyData* m_data;
public:
    void Data(MyData* data) { m_data = data; }
    ...
};

then I tried like this  void Data(MyData &data)  {m_data = data}
then I tried this   void Data(MyData data) { m_data = data} 
none of them worked. I think i am doing something wrong

Comment: I think you've got two instances of the data.  Have a look at the edit on an alternative technique

Comment: it is going to be a stupid question but if i set up the constructor like that, what do i do with this constructor ? 
MyWindow(int width, int height, const char* title=0) :
Fl_Window(width,height,title) {

Comment: Add the data before the title.  I have edited the example accordingly